# How to disable Events?

Tags: c#

I create the `btn1_MouseDown` event handler:

```cs
private void btn1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    btn1.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.click;
}
```

I want to disable that `btn1_MouseDown` event behind this `RadioButton` when it is checked. I mean to say when `RadioButton` is checked then this `btn1_MouseDown` event should not work.

```cs
private void r1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (r1.Checked == true)
        clock = 5;

    radioButton2.Enabled = false;
    radioButton3.Enabled = false;
    radioButton4.Enabled = false;     
}
```

Is that possible?

Comment: Why are you comparing a boolean to `true`?

Comment: @lc very simple - checked is nullable boolean so you have to compare to true :)

Comment: @AdamBilinski: This seems to be WinForms, where it is not a nullable `bool`, but a normal `bool`.

Comment: @AdamBilinski Really? Last I checked [`RadioButton.Checked`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.radiobutton.checked.aspx) was a `System.Boolean`

Comment: @lc of course you are right I was thinking about CheckBox :)

Comment: @AdamBilinski: [`CheckBox.Checked`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkbox.checked.aspx) is a `bool`, as well, not a `Nullable<bool>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

inside `r1_checkeChanged` add:

```
btn1.MouseDown -=btn1_MouseDown;
```

Comment: it will not go to complex code if i want to disable for 20 button's Events?

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the event:

```
btn1.MouseDown -= btn1_MouseDown
```

Of course don't forget to add it back again when you need it.

---

However, instead of doing that I would change your event handler's code to check the state of the radio button:

```
private void btn1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (!r1.Checked)
        btn1.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.click;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`1st option` can be to remove the event at radio button check_change event like this:

> btn1.MouseDown -=btn1_MouseDow;

but i dont prefer this way. 
`Second` is to add a flag at start of this event and check whether to execute the event or not
like this:

```
bool flag;

private void btn1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (flag) return;
    btn1.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.click;
}
```

Comment: i use more then one radio button and i just want to do this only for RadioButton1 not for other , then `flag` will fulfill my requirements ?

Comment: yes you can do `flag=true;` on `radiobutton1_checkchanged` only. it will work